# Separar datos de una tabla en 2 columnas diferentes

Tags: mysql, array, phpmyadmin

Tengo una consulta si es que alguien me puede ayudar, resulta que tengo que crear una tabla en donde los valores son una lista de códigos de productos, los cuales están separados por familia (en la imagen soy mas especifico)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que separar la tabla que, como pueden notar, es una sola repetida en ambas columnas. El tema es que los datos, por algún motivo están erróneos, la consulta esta bien hecha, pero en algún lugar del código se pierden... Entonces para no modificar nada de la tabla mejor hago una nueva, y en eso estoy.

Tengo que dejar los códigos que son **16xxx-x**  pertenecen a la medida de 1/2, y los de **20xxx-x** respectivamente a la columna de 5/8, como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado lo siguiente en la tabla:

Pensaba que haciendo un `array_slice()` o un `array_chunk()` podría manejarlo pero no logro dar con los resultados esperados, me marca algunos errores y no lo logro captar. O al parecer tengo un problema con los `arrays`, o no los estoy tratando bien.

```
    $media = array_chunk($col_codigoproducto, 0, 3);
    $cincoOctavos = array_chunk($col_codigoproducto, 3, 7);
```

Cuando aplico un `var_dump()` a mi variable `$col_codigoproducto` me entrega lo siguiente:

```
`string(11) "93234160506" string(11) "93234160808" string(11) "93234160905" 
 string(11) "93234161006" string(11) "9323420080K" string(11) "93234200907" 
 string(11) "93234201008" string(11) "93234201105"`
```

No creo que este tan perdido, pero cuando hago un `array_chunk` me entrega este error:

> Warning: array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in 
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\websystem\vista\index12.php on line 2412

Sé que hay muchos modos de hacerlo, estoy abierto a sugerencias, intente hacer otra consulta `SQL` con los mismos datos, con `LIMIT 0,3` a una tabla con los datos especificados, pero de hacer eso, tendría que hacer la misma consulta otra vez con la información inversa para que me muestra la otra aparte de la tabla, pero no se como debería hacerlo. Sé que se debería poder desde una consulta directa `SQL` pero no supe como hacerlo.

De ante mano gracias, disculpen si son un poco noobs las preguntas, pero voy despacito en esto. Aparte, llegue a trabajar sobre el código de otra persona, hecho hace por lo menos 15 años.

Les dejo el código con el que hago la tabla:

```
`<?php include_once('../persistencia/conexion.php');
$conexion = new conexion();

$SQL = "SELECT stock.codigo_producto,
        stock.stock_minimo,
        stock.stock_fisico
        FROM stock INNER JOIN producto
        ON stock.codigo_producto = producto.codigo
        WHERE producto.familia = '93234'
        AND stock.codigo_sucursal = '01'
        ORDER BY codigo_producto ASC";`

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion->conectarse(), $SQL );
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $filaAnterior = 0;

    @$col_codigoproducto = $row['codigo_producto'];


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                {
    @$col_stock_fisico = $row['stock_fisico'];
    @$col_codigoproducto = $row['codigo_producto'];
  echo "<tr>
<td width='75'><div>$largo[$y]</div></td>
<td width='75'><div>$agarre[$y]</div></td>
<td width='75'><div>$hilo[$y]</div></td>
<td width='75'>".substr($col_codigoproducto,5,5).'- 
'.substr($col_codigoproducto,10,5)."</td>
<td bgcolor='#B8CCE4' width='75'>".$col_stock_fisico."</td>
<td width='75'>".substr($col_codigoproducto,5,5).'- 
'.substr($col_codigoproducto,10,5)."</td>
<td bgcolor='#B8CCE4' width='75'>".$col_stock_fisico."</td>
<td width='150'>".$plano."</td>
</tr>";
}`
```

aquí dejo las tablas para que vean como están distribuidas.

```
`<table id="tabla" name="tabla" border="1" padding= "30px" >
<tr class="enunciado">
<td rowspan="2" colspan="3">
<div>MEDIDAS EN PULG.</div>
</td>
<td colspan="4">
<div>DIAMETROS &#216;</div>
</td>
<td rowspan="3">
<div><p>NORMA/PLANO</p><p>OBSERVACIONES</p></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="enunciado">
<td colspan="2">
<div>1/2 - 12 BSW</div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
<div>5/8 - 11 BSW</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="enunciado">
<td>            <div>LARGO</div>        </td>
  <td>
<div>AGARRE<div>
</td>
<td>
<div>HILO</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>CODIGO</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>ASUNTO</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>CODIGO</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>ASUNTO</div>
</td>
</tr>`
```

Answer (score 0):

yo haria algo asi, convierto ese codigo que tienes en una funcion:

```
function generarFila($result){ //pasas el resultado de la query
echo "<tr>"
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $col_stock_fisico = $row['stock_fisico'];
    $col_codigoproducto = $row['codigo_producto'];
    ?>
    <td width='75'>
        <div><?php echo $largo[$y];?></div>
    </td>
    <td width='75'>
       <div><?php echo $agarre[$y];?></div>
    </td>
    <td width='75'>
        <div><?php $hilo[$y];>?></div>
    </td>
    <td width='75'>
    <?php 
       echo substr($col_codigoproducto,5,5).'-'.substr($col_codigoproducto,10,5);
    ?>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor='#B8CCE4' width='75'>
      <?php echo $col_stock_fisico; ?>
    </td>
    <td width='75'> 
    <?php
         echo substr($col_codigoproducto,5,5).'-'.substr($col_codigoproducto,10,5);
    ?>
    </td>
    <td bgcolor='#B8CCE4' width='75'>
         <?php echo $col_stock_fisico; ?>
    </td>
    <td width='150'>
         <?php echo $plano; ?>
    </td>
<?php } echo "</tr>"?>
```

podrias hacer 2 consultas por cada medida y llamar a la funcion

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conexion->conectarse(), $SQL );
 generarFila($result);
 //ahora cambias el query por la otra medida y es lo mismo
 //$SQL = "new query";
 //$result = mysqli_query($conexion->conectarse(), $SQL );
 //generarFila($result);
```

ubiera sido mejor incluir la estructura de la tabla en los detalles de la pregunta para saber que consulta hacer

Comment: gracias ignacio lopez, ahi deje la tabla, voy a probar esto, les comento cualquier cosa. gracias

Comment: me refería a la tabla en la base de datos, de donde sacas el diametro? solo obtienes esto en la consulta                          
        stock.codigo_producto,
        stock.stock_minimo,
        stock.stock_fisico o el diámetro esta en el where producto.familia = '93234'

Comment: gracias amigo, ya lo solucione, mas rato te publico la solución, pero te adelanto que fue agregando un valor en blanco a los arreglos que necesitaba, y con un for, recorriendo 5 veces en vez de 4 los resultados de la consulta. así en la posicion 0 de cada arreglo empezaba con un espacio vacío y automáticamente me cuadraba la tabla, gracias igual, saludos

Answer (score 0):

> bueno amigos cortito, solo tenia que agregar un espacio vacio a los
>   array en cuestion y en vez de recorrer 4 vece con el for, eran 5.

```
    $codigoarraytwo[] = ''; 
    $col_stock_fisicotwo[] = '';
    $vuelta = 0;
```

> esto fue fundamental, ya que al no agregar otro ciclo, solo me
>   reproduce 4 valores por columna.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        if($vuelta <= 3){ 
        $codigoarrayone[] = $row['codigo_producto'];         
        $col_stock_fisicoone[] = $row['stock_fisico'];
}else {
      $codigoarraytwo[] = $row['codigo_producto']; 
      $col_stock_fisicotwo[] = $row['stock_fisico'];
    }
     $vuelta++;
    }
    $vuelta = 0;
    $string =null;

     foreach ($codigoarraytwo  as $key => $value) 

{$string = $string."<tr>

<td width='75'><div>".$largoarreglo[$vuelta]."</div></td>
<td width='75'><div>".$agarrearreglo[$vuelta]."</div></td>
<td width='75'><div>".$hiloarreglo[$vuelta]."</div></td>
<td width='75'>".@substr($codigoarrayone[$vuelta],5,5).'-'.@substr($codigoarrayone[$vuelta],10,5)."</td>
<td bgcolor='#B8CCE4' width='75'>".@$col_stock_fisicoone[$vuelta]."</td>
<td width='75'>".substr($codigoarraytwo[$vuelta],5,5).'-'.substr($codigoarraytwo[$vuelta],10,5)."</td>
<td bgcolor='#B8CCE4' width='75'>".$col_stock_fisicotwo[$vuelta]."</td>
<td width='150'>".$plano."</td>";
$vuelta++;
}
echo $string."
</tr>
</tbody>";
 ?>
```

> se desordeno un poco, lo siento por eso. saludos comunidad, y espero
>   que a alguien le sirva alguna vez.